# DB query taking wrong table name on laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydb.posts' 
doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts` where 
`title` = asdas)
```

Table name in database is post, but it going to to posts.

### Post.php

```
class Post extends Model{}
```

Comment: The details you have given are really complete, important and will help others solve your problem! Great work!

Comment: How did you get on @Cristal ?

Answer (score 1):

So you need to declare the table you wish to load if it doesn't fit under laravel default convention. set table as a class property :

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'post';
}
```